# How do you highlight span_near queries in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, highlighting

I am attempting to highlight a document based on a `span_near` query in Elasticsearch **2.1.1**, and ES is incorrectly highlighting a term that is not actually a hit because it is outside the span in question.

The steps I'm executing are:

**Create the index**

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/' -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "tweet": {
            "properties": {
                "message": {
                    "type": "string", 
                    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets", 
                    "store": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

**Index the document**

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1?refresh=true' -d '{
    "message" : "A new bonsai tree in the office. Bonsai!"
}'
```

**Search**

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "span_near" : {
            "clauses" : [
                {"span_term": {"message": "new"}}, 
                {"span_term": {"message": "bonsai"}}
            ], 
            "slop": 1, 
            "in_order": false
        }
    }, 
    "highlight": {"fields": {"message": {"type": "plain"}}}
}'
```

The search above is returning:

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.13561106,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "twitter",
      "_type" : "tweet",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.13561106,
      "_source":{"message" : "A new bonsai tree in the office. Bonsai!"},
      "highlight" : {
        "message" : [ "A <em>new</em> <em>bonsai</em> tree in the office. <em>Bonsai</em>!" ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, it is incorrectly highlighting the occurrence of "Bonsai" at the end of the field that is not within 1 word of "new". A couple of things to note:

1. This same exact set of steps produces **correct** highlighting results against Elasticsearch **1.5.2**.
2. There is an open bug for `span_near` queries not working using the Fast Vector Highlighter (FVH) -- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5496 -- which is why I'm attempting to use the `plain` highlighter above

Is there something I'm missing in order to get highlighting to work with `span_near` queries?

Comment: Your query is working fine on`ES 2.0`, I am not able to find any document that says something changed in `highlighting` from 2.0 to 2.1

Comment: @ChintanShah25 I also confirmed that the highlighting works correctly on ES 2.0.2. Seems like this must be a highlighter bug in 2.1...

Comment: I could not find anything in [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-2.1.html), could you give it a shot to [highlight query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_highlight_query), I mean copy your query as it is to highlight query and see if it works?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 I get the same incorrect results passing the same query in using `highlight_query`

Comment: Well then I would suggest opening an issue on [github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this is a known bug in ES v2.1.1, and it is fixed by this pull request:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/15516.

According to the labels on that PR, this bug fix will be part of v2.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I went back and played with this a bit on a test environment and what I think is happening is you are misunderstanding what the span_near query is doing. I'm using Sense to do this so syntactically it may look a little different but you should be able to follow along and reproduce this.

I first went through and created an index with mappings

```
PUT /testindex
{
   "mappings": {
      "post": {
         "properties": {
            "message": {
               "type": "string",
               "store": true,
               "analyzer": "english",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

I omitted your one property for term_vector it had no impact on my test and I figured it was some legacy property left over from you trying to the vector highlighting.

I then updated the index with some data

```
PUT /testindex/post/1
{
    "message": "Bonsai new. A new bonsai tree in the office. Bonsai!"
}
```

And then executed your query which gave me the same results ( won't post that as it is the same as listed above).

Where I think the confusion is coming in is in blurring what the highligher is doing vs span_near. The query is searching for terms new and bonsai with a slop of one which is working.
To test this add the following entries:

```
PUT /testindex/post/2
{
    "message": "Bonsai blah blah new blah blah bonsai tree in the office Bonsai!"
}
```

Running your query returns no result as the distance of new to bonsai is now greater than one. While changing the slop to something like 5 or 6 would get you matches returned.

This works independent of highlighting. The highlighting is looking at the terms independent of the span query but if the term is within the returned response, highlighting will be applied to the term(s), to which we see it is. Highlighting definitely went through some changes in 2.0+ as we had some re-writes once we move to the 2.0 engine.

Based upon the changes I have seen highlighting now seems to work independent of the query as if it is applied to the response post event. I may be wrong on this but it looks as if it is doing exactly as expected. You see Bonsai highlighted because it was one of the terms to be searched upon. Highlighting is not factoring in the slop parameter or span_near rule only that the two chained terms exist in the result.

We read the entry you entered as a sentence however ES strips the punctuation and looks at the white space is delimiters. Indexing and searching what you entered results in a match because there are two terms within 1 interval of one another. Highlighting is then applied to the result based on the terms searched for not the proximity into which they fell of one another.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something very similar and did a comparison between ES 1.7 and 2.3 and wrote it up on the ES discussion boards.   It's now a github issue in case anyone wants to track: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18035